# 'Invalidad datatype' when trying to create table with DATETIME. - APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm very new with Apex and i'm trying to create a table in the 'SQL Workshop' with DATETIME as a type but it says that is an invalid datatype here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Incidente(
NumReporte  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Tipo CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Lugar CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Comentarios CHAR(100),
    MatriculaRep VARCHAR(9)NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(NumReporte),
    FOREIGN KEY(MatriculaRep) REFERENCES Persona(Matricula)
```

)

Comment: It is an invalid data type... an Oracle DATE is a datetime already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `datetime` is not a data type in Oracle.  A `date` contains a day and a time component to the second.  A `timestamp` adds the ability to store fractional seconds.  A `timestamp with time zone` lets you store the time zone as well.

Second, you don't want to declare columns `char(20)`, `char(40)`, or `char(100)`.  It makes no sense to force Oracle to store 100 bytes of commentary data in the `comentarios` column for every row when it's almost certain that you don't have that much data for every row.  There is no penalty to using a `varchar2` so you basically always want to use `varchar2`.  Some people would suggest abandoning `char` entirely.  Others would allow short `char` columns when the underlying data really is fixed width (i.e. a single character flag column, a two character state code, etc.)